# Are villagers who are asked to leave the island able to come back?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I've just read about being able to kick villagers off your island via not talking to them for a few days, waiting until they walk around with a dark cloud over their head, then finally talking to them and, when given the choice, ask them to leave.

If the option is given say to ask a villager to leave, can that villager still be encountered through Mystery Islands and invited to the island again? Or is it a permanent and one-time decision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked a villager to leave and on my second mystery island I ran into them. So yes, it can happen. Not sure what the odds are, but I was honestly blown away.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, the villager can be invited back. Not sure on the Mystery Island encounter part, as I've only seen this done [through Amiibo re-invites](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnimalCrossing/comments/fpu4dd/everything_ive_found_out_about_villagers_campers/).